# Check for valid utf8 string in Python

Tags: python, json, utf-8, invalid-characters

I'm reading filenames from file system and I want to send them as JSON encoded array. The problem is that files on file system can be stored in invalid encoding, and I need to handle this situation to omit invalid filenames before passing it to `json.dump`, otherwise it will fail.

Is there a way to check that my string (filename) contains valid utf-8 chars?

Comment: Shock me. *Why* would the files not have valid UTF-8 filenames?

Comment: it's the file name that is not encoded in utf-8 or is it the data in the file ?? i m confused.

Comment: How about buggy software that creates filenames based on ID3 tags without checking the encoding?  Or mounting (with the wrong options) an old filesystem that uses an odd character encoding for filenames?

Comment: Invalid encoding can be big problem when moving data from old (non utf-8) systems (like WinXP with non-US/EN locale) and especially files in .zip and .rar archives files created on these systems

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because the filename/filesystem could be corrupted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about trying the following?

```
valid_utf8 = True
try:
    filename.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    valid_utf8 = False
```

... based on an answer to a similar question here: [How to write a check in python to see if file is valid UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269293/how-to-write-a-check-in-python-to-see-if-file-is-valid-utf-8/3269387#3269387)

Comment: if isinstance(filename, unicode):
        print "unicode string"

Comment: @mithuntnt: the question isn't asking about whether a Python string is a `unicode`; it's asking whether the bytes the make up a filename in the filesystem are valid UTF-8.

Comment: This will not catch strings that contain high/low surrogates (u+d800 to u+dfff).