# Replace all characters except for alphanumerics from all languages

Tags: python, regex

How to keep the special alphabet/character in a text file using Python?

Input text file:

```
abcÃ/cdéf@-www
```

I want to remove the symbol, but keep alphabet and special alphabet, symbol means `~!@#$%^*()_+{}<>:"|` and so on. After I tried to run my code to do so, here is what I got:

Output text file:

```
abc  cd f  www
```

The symbols have been removed and replaced with space which is what I want, but the special alphabets have been removed and replaced with space as well which I don't want. Is there any way to remove symbols but keep special alphabets only?

Expected output text file:

```
abcÃ cdéf  www
```

Here is my code:

```
string = open('abc.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', string)
open('abc.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(new_str)
```

Comment: ```new_str = ''.join([char fro char in string if char not in "~!@#$%^*()_+{}<>:\"|"])``` probably not best solution but still a working solution

Comment: @xiidref this is a solution, there is also an `isalpha` method that could work here: `"àbc".isalpha() # >> True`

Comment: Did you try removing the \n\. In your code?

Comment: @JuliusLimson ya, I had tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your second line with:

```
new_str = re.sub('[^\w\s.,;]', ' ', string)
```

Comment: you've included also `@` which he want to replace. Your answer is best, but you broke it including to string to much stuff.

Comment: @Marek. Something bad happend with my fingers. Now edited again.

Comment: I had tried replaced this code, but I got this error:
```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Works [pretty well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nLoEMdeKuKR6VoJx) except for the Hebrew (adds some extra spaces).

Comment: @JānisŠ. How to verify my text file is in non-utf8 encoded? How to solve it if it is non-utf8 encoded?

Comment: @Marek. Yes, it looks that '\w' does not apply correctly to Hebrew characters. However, if you use regex module (https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead of Python's built-in re module Hebrew characters have no spaces between them.

Comment: @EdisonToh problem is how do you open this file? You can tell python what kind of encoding file is using `open(fname, encoding="latin-1")` then strings will be properly loaded and everything should work like a charm. [See this](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html)

Comment: @EdisonToh. The answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269293/how-to-write-a-check-in-python-to-see-if-file-is-valid-utf-8) may help you to validate encoding of your file.

Comment: @JānisŠ. thanks for your answer, that's works for me! May I know is there any other encoding="xxx" besides encoding="latin-1"?

Comment: There are plenty of encodings. Look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: @JānisŠ. Thanks for your reply! I will look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify to remove the special characters/punctuation only

```
puncts = re.escape(string.punctuation)
print re.sub(r'['+ puncts +']', '', your_string)
```

Comment: You should avoid to use `+` to format string : https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36

Comment: I had tried replaced this code, but I got this error:

``UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: invalid continuation byte``.

Comment: Check your encoding in your interpreter or in your python script

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import re
string = open('abc.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
new_str = re.sub('[/~!@#$%^*()_+{}<>:"|-]', ' ', string) # put your characters to replace here
open('abc.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(new_str)
```

output is:

```
abcÃ cdéf  www
```

Comment: I had tried replaced this code, but I got this error:

``UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: invalid continuation byte``.